# visual studio 2015 "Add service reference" missing

Tags: visual-studio, wsdl

I need to import a **WSDL** and I do not see "**Add service reference**" on menu when I right click project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Service Reference not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196536/add-service-reference-not-appearing)

Answer (score -2):

> **To add a reference to a service in the current solution**
>
> In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project that you
>   want to add the service to, and then click Add Service Reference.
>
> The Add Service Reference dialog box appears.
>
> Click Discover.
>
> All WCF services in the current solution are added to the Service
>   list.
>
> In the Service list, expand the node for the service that you want to
>   use and select a service contract.
>
> In the Namespace box, enter the namespace that you want to use for the
>   reference.
>
> Click OK to add the reference to the project.
>
> A service client (proxy) is generated, and metadata describing the
>   service is added to the app.config file.

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628652(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Well I do not see "Add Service Reference" menu item at all. I did little more digging and looks like this happens when I create project using ASP.net 5 preview template in VS 2015. If I select ASP.net 4.6 template then it works fine. Any idea why that happens?
Thanks a lot.